# How does online streaming still play; while page is refreshed?

Tags: php

I need some help for my internet radio, It will take some time to play every time i refresh the page. How can i make it play continuously even i refresh it??

thankyou this is my code:

```
<div class="col c2">
  <h2><span>Live Streaming</span> </h2>
     <div id="container">
          <a href="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">Get the Flash Player</a> to see this player.
          <a href="http://www.shouthost.com/">Shoutcast &amp; Icecast Server</a>     
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shouthost.com/freeflashplayer/player/swfobject.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
 var s1 = new SWFObject('http://www.shouthost.com/freeflashplayer/player/player.swf',
 'player',"340","32","9","#FFFFFF");
 s1.addParam("allowfullscreen","true");
 s1.addParam("allowscriptaccess","always");
 s1.addParam("flashvars","skin=http://www.shouthost.com/freeflashplayer/skins/modieus.swf&title=Live Stream&type=sound&file=http://78.129.163.82:10729/;stream.mp3&13202692901&duration=99999&id=scplayer&autostart=true");
 s1.write("container");
      </script>   

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://hosted.muses.org/mrp.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
MRP.insert({
'url':'http://78.129.163.82:10729',
'codec':'mp3',
'volume':100,
'autoplay':true,
'buffering':5,
'title':'RADIO APOSTLE 102.6 MHZ',
'bgcolor':'#12880C',
'skin':'simple-red',
'width':300,
'height':122
});
        </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not, unless you do the refresh of the page via ajax and load the content into the page that way.

Why are you refreshing the page?

Comment: www.radioaposlte.com.np is my site... Need to go to different pages... But I want the flash player to remain playing...

Any help?

Comment: Site does not load for me, but anyway -- your only option is to either write the site to load content via ajax or use an iframe to put the player in and wrap the content of your other pages in that iframe so everything is navigated through it. Both will make it wonky to use the back button as well as screw up url usage to get to specific pages... There are solutions to fix that in ajax, but they do tend to be a bit more complex.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply!! My site is www.radioapostle.com.np

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have three options:

1. Open your player in a separate new browser window
2. Create a site that will be a single page application (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), so the browser keeps everything on one page without actually refreshing it.
3. Create a page that will have two frames - one with the player and the other one with your entire website

Comment: Thankyou!! Sounds advance coding needed; but let's see if there is any shortcut!!